# Codeigniter - set data to controller variable from within a model

Tags: codeigniter, scope

I am trying to save some debug data within my model, which will then be appeded to a debug variable $this->debug_data , which was declared public within the controller.

It seems the variable scope for the variable is limited to just controller and cant be set inside the model.

is there anyway i can do this.

I can do this fine within my custom 'libraries' which are being called within the same controller.

Comment: Help me to help you. Post some code.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access a property of the currently loaded controller from within a model in CI you'll need to do the following:

either in your Models specific method or within its constructor put:

```
$this->CI = & get_instance();
```

Then say you'll be able access your `debug_data` with:

```
$this->CI->debug_data;
```

Hope this helps!